# i want to UPDATE Fax table and FaxData table that link between Fax&employees tables

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

i made viewmodel view to allow me to use the 2 model (Fax&Faxdata) in my view 
but i have NULL value of SelectedEmployees in listboxfor 
what is the problem in my viewmodel ??

```
 namespace FaxProject.ViewModel
{
public class SendFaxVm
{

    public List<SelectListItem> Employees { set; get; }

    public int[] SelectedEmployees { set; get; }
    public Fax fax { set; get; }

  }
}
```

this is the view (Edite view)

```
@model FaxProject.ViewModel.SendFaxVm

    @using (Html.BeginForm("Edit","Fax"))
      {
      @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Fax</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.fax.Id)

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.fax.Courier_Num, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.fax.Courier_Num, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.fax.Courier_Num, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.fax.NumberOfPages, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.fax.NumberOfPages, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.fax.NumberOfPages, "", 
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Employees, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">

            @Html.ListBoxFor(a => a.SelectedEmployees, Model.Employees)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.SelectedEmployees)


        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Back" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

}

i got null exception in the listbox so how can i get the list of employees of edit it ??

```
 public ActionResult Edit (int id,SendFaxVm vm,Fax fax)
    {
        var faxindb = Db.Faxes.Single(f=>f.Id==id);
        faxindb.Courier_Num = fax.Courier_Num;
        faxindb.NumberOfPages = fax.NumberOfPages;
        faxindb.CompanyName = fax.CompanyName;
        faxindb.ReceivingDate = fax.ReceivingDate;
        faxindb.Attachment = fax.Attachment;
        faxindb.Subject = fax.Subject;
        Db.SaveChanges();

        foreach (var userId in vm.SelectedEmployees)
        {
            var faxdataindb = Db.FaxDatas.Single(f => f.FaxId == fax.Id);
            faxdataindb.EmpId = userId;
            //to do  : Save fd 

            Db.SaveChanges();
        }

        return RedirectToAction("FaxForm","Fax");
    }
```

this is the action in Fax controller ...

Comment: Post  the controller code to see what values are getting binded which will provide more details about why the values are null.

Comment: i updated the post and added it .

Comment: The  Code pasted is of Post action in Fax Controller, There should be a get method which will be getting the values that you will be using to populate the list view, Paste that part of the code too

Comment: public ActionResult EditForm()
        {
            var vm = new SendFaxVm();
            vm.Employees = Db.Employees.Select(a => new SelectListItem()
            {
                Value = a.Id.ToString(),
                Text = a.Name
            }).ToList();
            return View("EditeForm",vm);
        }

Comment: this is the code i was had an error in it and i fixed it and the null exception is solved :) but i have other error after i click the form button (The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Edit(Int32, FaxProject.ViewModel.SendFaxVm, FaxProject.Models.Fax)' in 'FaxProject.Controllers.FaxController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
Parameter name: parameters)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey You can improve couple of things.

```
public class SendFaxVm
{
    public List<SelectListItem> Employees { set; get; }
    public List<int> SelectedEmployees { set; get; }
    public Fax fax { set; get; }

  }
```

Change array to a List in your Model, You can also use IEnumerable here too. If you , Also follow this example to populate Listbox https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/771999/ASP-Net-MVC-How-to-create-a-ListBox

Comment: i have changed it to list<int> and i have the same exception ??!